# UISearchController glitches when placed in UINavigationItem - iOS 11+

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uisearchcontroller

I've a `UISearchController` in `FirstViewController`'s `navigationItem`. And the same in a `SecondViewController` and I push `SecondViewController` from `FirstViewController`.

When the user slides to go back, the below UI glitch is visible.

[image: UISearchController glitch while sliding back]

The area containing the `UISearchController` becomes dim. If the user goes back to `FirstViewController`, it looks good. But if the user stays in the `SecondViewController` after sliding a little, then this is what it looks like.

[image: Missing UISearchController in navigationItem]

The space which had the `searchController` is now empty. If the user scrolls up or down, the `searchController` becomes visible again.

Options tried to fix the issues

- using `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController` with `UITableView`
- toggling `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` property in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`
- setting `navigationItem.searchController` as `nil` in `viewWillDisappear`

Apart from this issue, when I use `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`, the `searchController` hides under the title and comes out at a slightly high speed than the native apps like Messages, Mail. 
And when I use `UITableViewController`, the animation is smooth but the searchController gets struck halfway if the user does not slide up or down fully, like shown below. This happens both with and without large titles.

[image: UISearchController getting struck]

My usecase can also be achieved, if someone can answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278159/uisearchcontroller-in-navigationitem-ios-11-apple-way).

UPDATE:
setting `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` as `true` in `SecondViewController` did resolve the issue. But there is a slight unwanted jerk in the tableview, if the user slides to go back but then changes his/her mind.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.. It's working for me. I hope it's working for you too.

**Objective-C**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        [self.navigationController.view setNeedsLayout]; 
        [self.navigationController.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
         self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()     
         self.navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

**if it not working then set animation NO or false when you push or present ViewController**

Comment: this worked to an extent but not fully. the spacing where the glitch occurred got reduced, but still it was slightly visible. and, setting an animation to false is not even an option in our app, that will give inconsistent user experience.