# UISearchController with large titles crashes in Tab bar with "Only one palette with a top boundary edge can be active outside of a transition"

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, ios11, uisearchcontroller, preferslargetitles

I have multiple tabs in a UITabBarController. All of them have a UINavigationBar with large titles and a iOS-11-built-in-search-bar. However, switching between the tabs makes the app crash with

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'Only one palette with a top boundary edge can be active outside of a transition. Current active palette is 
<_UINavigationControllerManagedSearchPalette: 0x7fc399b49980; frame = (0 96; 375 52); layer = <CALayer: 0x60c0004383a0>>'
```

I've tested the workaround posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46382723/511299 without success. This question did not use a UITabBarController.

I've added this code to `viewDidAppear`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
```

and this to `viewWillDisappear`:

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
```

Adding prints to each method to check the order verifies that is nils out the previous view before setting it on the appearing view.

It crashes after going from tab 0 to tab 1, then back to tab 0. I do not even need to scroll down to show the searchbar.

Full stack trace:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Only one palette with a top boundary edge can be active outside of a transition. Current active palette is <_UINavigationControllerManagedSearchPalette: 0x7fea7dcaf880; frame = (0 44; 375 52); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000062ac20>>'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b8381e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109cda031 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b8ad975 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
3   UIKit                               0x000000010e67dec6 -[UINavigationController(_UIPalette) attachPalette:isPinned:] + 521
4   UIKit                               0x000000010e659afd -[UINavigationController _createAndAttachSearchPaletteForTopViewControllerIfNecessary:] + 585
5   UIKit                               0x000000010e677c10 -[UINavigationController _navigationItemDidUpdateSearchController:oldSearchController:] + 419
6   UIKit                               0x000000010f0737a1 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS navigationItemUpdatedSearchController:oldSearchController:animated:] + 160
7   UIKit                               0x000000010edf15c4 -[UINavigationItem setSearchController:] + 135
8   Appmost                             0x0000000107e5902e _T07Appmost25JsonCreatedViewControllerC14setupSearchBaryyFyycfU_ + 1486
9   Appmost                             0x0000000107e590cd _T07Appmost25JsonCreatedViewControllerC14setupSearchBaryyFyycfU_TA + 13
10  Appmost                             0x0000000107cbcb7d _T0Ieg_IeyB_TR + 45
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124c97ab _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124ca7ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124d58cf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 628
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b7fac99 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b7beea6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2342
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b7be30b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113adaa73 GSEventRunModal + 62
18  UIKit                               0x000000010e482057 UIApplicationMain + 159
19  Appmost                             0x0000000107f72167 main + 55
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112547955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSExceptio
```

Comment: Do you get this crash while switching from a tab with active search?

Comment: try this searchController.isActive = false

Comment: Added description to reproduce to the question

Comment: @guru Adding `searchController.isActive = false` in viewWillDisapperar does not help.

Comment: @Sunkas Does every tab have it's own `UINavigationController` or your `UITabBarController` is embedded into `UINavigationController`? Also a whole stack trace of the crash would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, every tab has it's own `UINavigationController`. It would be weird otherwise. Will attach a full stack trace to question!

Comment: @Sunkas I have created a sample project for reproducing the issue but unfortunately it is not recreated Could you please have look on this https://github.com/Arunjos/TabBarWithSearchViewController

Comment: @arunjos007 You forgot to enable largeTitles, and calling super in viewDidDissappear. But your code seems to work otherwise. Placing the code in viewDidAppear reproduces it though. I also need to dynamically hide/show the searchbar as a feature. But perhaps this can be done in other places than viewWillAppear. Will get back to you how your solution worked.

Comment: @Sunkas updated the repo with changes but seems works fine here, anyway please check and let me know

Comment: @arunjos077, write this as an answer before it expires (1 hour) and I'll award you the bounty. The answer was to just setup the search-bar in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @Sunkas Okay thanks! I have added it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to recreate the issue but everything seems fine when I added the code in `func viewDidLoad()`

Below is the code for adding search view controller in iOS11

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        //Setup Search Controller
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        self.searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.navigationItem.title = "Heading 2"
    }
```

I have also created a demo project for you please find it in [Github Here](https://github.com/Arunjos/TabBarWithSearchViewController)

Comment: The main issue seems to be unloading and loading again in viewDidDissappear/viewDidAppear. Setting up the searchbar in viewDidLoad did work just fine. Must have been some other issue before that made me move away from this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code in viewDidLoad() and it's working

Try to add this line of code:

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation
```

Comment: Do you use a UITabBarController as well? With another seachController in that one? That seems to be the issue.

Comment: Still crashes with your solution. Tried both with false and true.

Answer (score 0):

These lines solved my problem.

```
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
```