# UISearchController / UINavigationBar shows broken animation when used within UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have this `NavigationController` hat has Large Titles enabled for its `NavigationBar`. The root `ViewController` has a `SearchController`, and hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling is set to True in the `ViewController`'s `NavigationItem` as I don't want the `SearchBar` to be always visible. The `ViewController` has a `TableView` and when you tap on one of its items a new instance of the same `ViewController` will be pushed onto the Navigation stack using a storyboard segue. However, when looking at the transition between the current and the new `ViewController` one can observe that the animation doesn't look right: As soon as the new `ViewController` is moved in the `SearchBar` becomes empty, just showing its background. When the new `ViewController` is finally fully visible, the `SearchBar` will go away without any animation.

This is how I add the `SearchController` (nothing fancy here):

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    }
}
```

And so it looks like when navigating from "One" to "Two":

[UISearchController / UINavigationBar shows broken animation when used within UINavigationController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc7iO.gif)

[image]

Is there a way to make this look nicer? Of course, in the new `ViewController` the `SearchBar` should not be initially visible, so it has to go away somehow. But I would think that the `SearchBar` on the old `ViewController` perhaps should be faded out somehow instead of staying there and then suddenly hiding when the transition to the new `ViewController` is finished. Hopefully I'm just doing something wrong here...

Thanks and Merry Xmas to all of you,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found something very useful that I just couldn't find before asking my question:

[Broken UISearchBar animation embedded in NavigationItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301813/broken-uisearchbar-animation-embedded-in-navigationitem)

Too bad this is known since iOS 11 and still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the search controller to nil in the viewWillDissappear method.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
}
```

Comment: This actually seems to improve things a bit as now the expanded `SearchBar` in "One" will be moved off-screen as part of the transition to "Two". In "Two" the flickering that can be seen in my video is gone. I'm not sure though, if the `SearchBar` is intended to be animated that way. So I guess I will do some more testing going from there.