# UINavigationController + UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

**Summary**

`UINavigationController` is showing broken animation when a child `UIViewController` has a `UISearchController` embedded into the navigation item's search controller.

This only happens if I set the `UISearchController` in the navigation item.

In the image below there are 2 examples:

1. Change Location `ViewController` - has animation lag when clicking on the `Back` (Settings) button.
2. Customize `ViewController` - works fine.

**Flow**

> UITableViewController > UIViewController with UISearchController embeded inside the navigation item

[image: image description]

**Findings**

I have researched this behavior and found some answers that described a similar behavior but not exactly the same as I have setup.

Trying to implement a solution suggested in the below post by setting the navigation item search controller to `nil` - did not solve this behavior:

[Broken UISearchBar animation embedded in NavigationItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301813/broken-uisearchbar-animation-embedded-in-navigationitem)

The code is below. Thanks in advance.

```
class ChangeLocationViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var locationBanner: CustomView!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let loadingBanner = LoadingBanner()

    var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
    var searchController: UISearchController?
    let locationManager = LocationManager.shared

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.locationManagerDelegate = self

        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(AppSettings.googleAPIKey)

        self.definesPresentationContext = true;


        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self

        let autoCompletedFilter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        autoCompletedFilter.type = .city
        resultsViewController?.autocompleteFilter = autoCompletedFilter

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "Search a place".localized
        searchController?.delegate = self

        // Setting the search controller [when it is not set, everything works great :)]
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Removing the search controller
        self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried the code `self.navigationItem.searchController = nil` in `viewDidDisappear` instead of `viewWillDisappear` ?

Comment: Same results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set `navigationItem.searchController` to `nil` when the other view controller appears as well.

```
class ChangeLocationViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        /* searchController */
        searchController.isActive = false
        navigationItem.searchController = nil
    }
}

class SettingsTableController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        /* searchController */
        navigationItem.searchController = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it but the animation lag remains. Thanks.

Comment: I just found out that when I click on the tab bar to go back to the previous screen instead of clicking on the navigation back button - it is working properly. Any idea what can cause it only in the navigation bar?